# Swift - Adding a pickerView to a textfield in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am struggling a bit with optionals and setting up views and subviews by using an @IBOutlet. I am currently trying to create a controller to add a user to the database. One of my fields is related to the user's gender, so I want it to be linked to a UIPickerView. **I am not using Storyboard.**

I removed all the other fields from my code to make it a lot shorter and readable, but it will also have other UIPickerView fields (like birthday).

**Can someone help me with my code so that my textfield will display a UIPickerView when selected?**

```
class AddUserController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

var picker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

var genderData = ["Male", "Female"]

// Containers
let inputsContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()

// Subviews
@IBOutlet weak var genderTextField: UITextField! = {
    var gender = UITextField()
    gender.placeholder = "Gender"
    gender.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    gender.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    gender.autocorrectionType = .No

    let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 30))
    lbl.text = "GENDER"
    lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)
    gender.leftView = lbl
    return gender
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker = UIPickerView()

    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.hidden = true

    genderTextField?.delegate = self
    genderTextField?.inputView = picker
    genderTextField?.text = genderData[0]

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)

    view.addSubview(inputsContainerView)

    setupInputsContainerView()
}

// Picker functions
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return genderData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return genderData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    genderTextField.text = genderData[row]
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    picker.hidden = true
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    picker.hidden = false
    return true
}

// Setup all the views
func setupInputsContainerView() {
    inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    inputsContainerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).active = true
    inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).active = true
    inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(40).active = true

    inputsContainerView.addSubview(genderTextField)

    genderTextField.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(inputsContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 12).active = true
    genderTextField.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(inputsContainerView.topAnchor).active = true
    genderTextField.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(inputsContainerView.widthAnchor).active = true
    genderTextField.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(inputsContainerView.heightAnchor).active = true
}
}
```

Comment: see this it helps you http://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/

Comment: If you are open to using 3rd party libraries, ActionSheetPickerView-3.0 is a pretty decent library and is easy to use. https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Answer (score 0):

genderTextField is getting created every time you call that.

```
genderTextField?.delegate = self
genderTextField?.inputView = picker
genderTextField?.text = genderData[0]
```

All these are different objects

```
inputsContainerView.addSubview(genderTextField)
```

What you added here is also different. So the textField you adedd to the view and the delegate/datasource you added are all different.  One quick solution is to move

```
genderTextField?.delegate = self
genderTextField?.inputView = picker
genderTextField?.text = genderData[0]
```

these code after this line `inputsContainerView.addSubview(genderTextField)`